# How can I script xrandr's scale function to switch to the next or previous resolution in a predefined list?

Tags: shell-script, keyboard-shortcuts, xrandr

`xrandr` has a nifty feature that lets you scale your entire screen so that your virtual resolution is larger or smaller than your actual resolution. I use it on my netbook's 1024x600 resolution screen to work in a 1280x750 resolution workspace. Can I set up keyboard shortcuts to increase/decrease/reset the scale factor I'm currently using? Some applications do great with the extra space, while some are harder to read. I know how to set up keyboard shortcuts in my distribution already, but I don't know how I can make xrandr accept this sort of differential input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the following script so that I could change my scale factor dynamically using keyboard shortcuts on my Dell Mini 10v netbook:

```
#!/bin/bash
#/usr/local/bin/xrandr-scale-tool

#first, we read the config files
if [ -r ~/.config/xrandr-scale-tool/xscale ] 
  then 
    xscale=$(~/.config/xrandr-scale-tool/xscale 
fi
if [ ! -e ~/.config/xrandr-scale-tool/output ] 
  then 
    output=LVDS1 
    echo $output>~/.config/xrandr-scale-tool/output 
fi
if [ ! -e ~/.config/xrandr-scale-tool/baseresx ] 
  then 
    baseresx=1024 
    echo $baseresx>~/.config/xrandr-scale-tool/baseresx 
fi
if [ ! -e ~/.config/xrandr-scale-tool/baseresy ] 
  then 
    baseresy=600 
    echo $baseresy>~/.config/xrandr-scale-tool/baseresy 
fi

#if they aren't readable, exit with status 1
if [ ! -r ~/.config/xrandr-scale-tool/xscale ] || [ ! -r ~/.config/xrandr-scale-tool/baseresx ] || [ ! -r ~/.config/xrandr-scale-tool/baseresy ] || [ ! -r ~/.config/xrandr-scale-tool/output ] 
  then 
    echo A config file could not be read 
    exit 1 
fi

#now, we check the first argument to see what to do
if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    #restore from settings
    xrandr --output $output --scale ${xscale}x${xscale} --panning 0x0+0+0
    xrandr --output $output --scale ${xscale}x${xscale} --panning `xrandr -q | awk -F'current' -F',' 'NR==1 {gsub("( |current)","");print $2}'`
fi

if [ "$1" == "+" ]
  then
    #increment and apply
    amt=$2
    xscale=`echo $xscale+$amt|bc`
    xrandr --output $output --scale ${xscale}x${xscale} --panning 0x0+0+0
    xrandr --output $output --scale ${xscale}x${xscale} --panning `xrandr -q | awk -F'current' -F',' 'NR==1 {gsub("( |current)","");print $2}'`
    sleep 2
    notify-send "Scale Factor: $xscale" --icon=display
fi

if [ "$1" == "-" ]
  then
    #decrement and apply
    amt=$2
    xscale=`echo $xscale-$amt|bc`
    xrandr --output $output --scale ${xscale}x${xscale} --panning 0x0+0+0
    xrandr --output $output --scale ${xscale}x${xscale} --panning `xrandr -q | awk -F'current' -F',' 'NR==1 {gsub("( |current)","");print $2}'`
    sleep 2
    notify-send "Scale Factor: $xscale" --icon=display
fi

if [ "$1" == "reset" ]
  then
    #reset
    xscale=1
    xrandr --output $output --scale ${xscale}x${xscale} --panning `echo $xscale*$baseresx|bc`x`echo $xscale*$baseresy|bc`
    sleep 2
    notify-send "Scale Factor: $xscale" --icon=display
fi

#record changes in scale to file before exiting
echo $xscale>~/.config/xrandr-scale-tool/xscale
exit 0
```

This script assumes that your default resolution is 1024x600, and you're using the display on LVDS1. If this isn't the case, edit the files in `~/.config/xrandr-scale-tool` to reflect this (config files are generated after the first run).

This script can be run  in four ways:
`xrandr-scale-tool` restores scale settings from the config file, which is saved on each run
`xrandr-scale-tool + 0.1` increments the scale by 0.1. You can use any number here
`xrandr-scale-tool - 0.1` decrements the scale by 0.1. Again, any number works
`xrandr-scale-tool reset` resets the scale to 1.
Each time the scale is changed, `notify-send` is run to show you the current scale factor via a notification.

The way I set mine up is that `xrandr-scale-tool + 0.125` is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>, `xrandr-scale-tool - 0.125` is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>, and `xrandr-scale-tool reset` is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. `xrandr-scale-tool` is run, with no arguments, on login, so that whichever scale I was using before is in use on my next login.

Comment: This answer doesn't sound at all like what your question was looking for. Your question sounds like you want to know how to set up keyboard bindings, not control `xrandr` via a script. If this is indeed what you meant, can you update your question to reflect that?